# GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OZc4sJ3 404 (Not Found) socket.io error in Next JS

Tags: next.js, socket.io

I am making a chat Application in next.js in the pages router and i am using socket.io library, I am getting this error `GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OZc5Mqk 404 (Not Found)`, Below is my code:

client side -

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
let socket;

const Home = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
  const [allMessages, setAllMessages] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    socketInitializer();
  }, [])

  const socketInitializer = async () => {
    await fetch('/api/hello');
    socket = io()



    socket.on('receive-message', msg => {
      console.log(msg)
      setAllMessages(pre => [...pre, data])
    })
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('send-message', {
      username, message
    })
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Chat App</h1>
      <p>Enter a username</p>
      <input type="text" value={username} name='username' onChange={(e) => { setUsername(e.target.value) }} className='border border-black' />

  {allMessages.map(({username, message}, index) => {
    return <p key={index}>
      {username} : {message}
    </p>
  })}

  {username && <div>
    <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" value={message} name='message' onChange={(e) => { setMessage(e.target.value) }} className='border border-black' />
    </form>
  </div>}
</div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

server side -

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io'

export default function SocketHandler(req, res) {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log('Socket is already running')
  } else {
    console.log('Socket is initializing');
    const io = new Server(res.socket.server);
    res.socket.server.io = io
    
    io.on('connection', socket => {
        socket.on('send-message', msg => {
            io.emit('receive-message', msg)
      })
    })
  }
  res.end()
}
```

I think I am getting this error from client side when calling the io(), I have tried using io.connect & io('http://localhost:3000') did not work,  Please help!!!